# Teechart Negative Scale Series - Stacking

Tags: activex, teechart

My Requirement is that we have a some products having both positive and negative values. Both values are displayed using 2 different series. The problem is the stacking of chart shown in legend and actual display doesn't match.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of writing this answer, I find the question is a bit vague or unclear.

However, an easy way to control what is shown in the legend is by removing all the current series from it setting `ShowInLegend=false`. Then, you can add as many "dummy" series as items you want to show in the legend. You can give a Color and a Title to that dummy series so the legend will show them. You don't need to populate these dummy series with data.

If this answer doesn't help you, please edit the question providing more accurate information.

Comment: Hi, The problem is if you see the chart drawn and legend, light Green Color is shown at the center for both the product in legend, where as in chart drawn it is not.

Comment: I'm not sure about what sequence of colors and strings you want to show in the legend, but with the answer above you can fully control it. Give it a try and tell us if you find any problem with it.